# JPA Criteria select all instances with max values in their groups

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api, correlated-subquery

Is there a way to write with JPA 2 `CriteriaBuilder` the equivalent of the following query?

```sql
select * from season s1
where end = (
    select max(end)
    from season s2
    where s1.contest_id=s2.contest_id
);
```

In JPQL this query is:

```
Select s1 from Season s1 
where s1.end = (
    select max(s2.end)
    from Season s2
    where s1.contest=s2.contest
)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work, with `contest` being either a basic Integer property, or a `ManyToOne` property pointing to another non-basic Entity.

```
EntityManger em;      //to be injected or constructed

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Season> cq = cb.createQuery(Season.class);
Subquery<Date> sq = cq.subquery(Date.class);
Root<Season> s1 = cq.from(Season.class);
Root<Season> s2 = sq.from(Season.class);
sq.select(cb.greatest(s2.get(Season_.end)));
sq.where(cb.equal(s2.get(Season_.contest), s1.get(Season_.contest)));
cq.where(cb.equal(s1.get(Season_.end), sq));
List<Season> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```