# How to write hibernate criteria for query with subselect and max

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

I have an entity with this fields:

- id (pk)
- Id_remuneration_str
- Id_salary_item
- Year
- Month
- price

This entity stores prices for each period and for each remuneration structure and salary item, and i need a query to retrieve the last price for every remuneration structure and salary item.

The sql query that works is this:

```
select * from ep_remuneration_str_price p1 
where ((100*year) + month) =  
( 
 select max(((100*year) + month)) 
 from ep_remuneration_str_price p2 
 where p1.id_remuneration_str = p2.id_remuneration_str and 
 p1.id_salary_item = p2.id_salary_item 
 group by ID_SALARY_ITEM
);
```

How can i translate to a criteria query?

Thanks in advance

Hi everyone, to simply the query i added a date in my entity to avoid operation between year and month

```
select * from ep_remuneration_str_price
where date in 
(  select max(date) 
from ep_remuneration_str_price pinner
where ep_remuneration_str_price.id_remuneration_str = pinner.id_remuneration_str and
   ep_remuneration_str_price.id_salary_item = pinner.id_salary_item
group by id_remuneration_str,ID_SALARY_ITEM
);
```

And i tried this peace of code:

```
        DetachedCriteria maxDateQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(LocalDate.class, "p_inner");
    ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
    proj.add(Projections.max("date"));
    proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("id_remuneration_str"));
    proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("idSalaryItem"));
    maxDateQuery.setProjection(proj);
    maxDateQuery.add(Expression.eqProperty("ep_remuneration_str_price.id_remuneration_str", "p_inner.id_remuneration_str"));
    maxDateQuery.add(Expression.eqProperty("ep_remuneration_str_price.id_salary_item", "p_inner.id_salary_item"));

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<RemunerationStructurePriceEntity> criteriaQuery = this.getCriteriaQuery();
    Root<RemunerationStructurePriceEntity> from = this.getCriteriaFrom(criteriaQuery);

    Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.in(from.get("date")).value(maxDateQuery);

    List<RemunerationStructurePriceEntity> result = (List<RemunerationStructurePriceEntity>) findByCriteriaQuery(criteriaQuery, from, criteriaBuilder, predicate);
```

I recieve this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [DetachableCriteria(CriteriaImpl(org.joda.time.LocalDate:p_inner[][ep_remuneration_str_price.id_remuneration_str=p_inner.id_remuneration_str, ep_remuneration_str_price.id_salary_item=p_inner.id_salary_item][max(date), id_remuneration_str, idSalaryItem]))] did not match expected type [org.joda.time.LocalDate (n/a)] at java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [DetachableCriteria(CriteriaImpl(org.joda.time.LocalDate:p_inner[][ep_remuneration_str_price.id_remuneration_str=p_inner.id_remuneration_str, ep_remuneration_str_price.id_salary_item=p_inner.id_salary_item][max(date), id_remuneration_str, idSalaryItem]))] did not match expected type [org.joda.time.LocalDate (n/a)]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: It is resolver by perissf in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400532/jpa-criteria-select-all-instances-with-max-values-in-their-groups

Comment: Thanks Pere, I will try

Comment: It works!!! thanks a lot!!