# Generating predicate for latest date value

Tags: spring, jpa, predicate, criteria-api

I need to create a predicate to fetch data from a table where `regId = ? (||) or (&&) estCode = ? && latest (referralEntryDate)`

fetch the data for latest date

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ReviewMedicalStatus> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

    List<Predicate> predicatesReg = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    if (revStatusDto.getRegId() != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(revStatusDto.getRegId())) {
        predicatesReg.add(cb.equal(root.get("regId"), revStatusDto.getRegId()));
    }
    if (revStatusDto.getEstCode() != null && !StringUtils.isEmpty(revStatusDto.getEstCode())) {
        predicatesReg.add(cb.equal(root.get("estCode"), revStatusDto.getEstCode()));
    }

    Expression maxExpression = cb.max(root.get("referralEntryDate"));
    predicatesReg.add(maxExpression);
    //predicatesReg.add(cb.max(root.get("referralEntryDate")));
    return cb.and(predicatesReg.toArray(new Predicate[predicatesReg.size()]));
}
```

This is failing as the expression can't be passed as a parameter to predicate. How can I get the data for latest `referralEntryDate`?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `max` you have to use `greatest` for dates. Max is for `Numeric` types. In order to put it in a predicate you need to make a subquery out of it. Reference: [JPA Criteria select all instances with max values in their groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400532/jpa-criteria-select-all-instances-with-max-values-in-their-groups). This isn't exactly your set of entities, but it should give you the idea:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
// make main query for Content
CriteriaQuery<Content> q = cb.createQuery(Content.class);
Root<Content> c = q.from(Content.class);

// make subquery for date
Subquery<Date> sq = q.subquery(Date.class);
Root<Content> c2 = sq.from(Content.class);

// get the max date in the subquery
sq.select(cb.greatest(c2.<Date>get("date")));

// make a predicate out of the subquery
Predicate p = cb.equal(c.get("date"), sq);

// assign predicate to the main query
q.where(p);        

// and get the results
Content r = em.createQuery(q).getSingleResult();
System.out.println(r);
```