# How to join an entity with custom select using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a scenario where I need to get the row with maximum date. The SQL query for this would be

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM course c 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT moduleId ,MAX(endDate) AS max_date
   FROM course
   WHERE moduleId = 12345
   GROUP BY moduleId
) customSelect
ON customSelect.moduleId = c.moduleId AND c.endDate = customSelect.max_date
WHERE c.moduleId = 12345
```

I need to convert this query to JPA using CriteriaBuilder.Since this isn't a direct entity join,  rather a selection join to root entity, I'm having trouble to figure out how to join the custom select part to the root entity **Course** with below syntax:

```
   CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<Course> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Course.class);
   Root<Course> root = criteriaQuery.from(Course.class);
```

And then how to root.join(JoinType.INNER) to join customSelect part?

If someone can show some pointers to the syntax of of joining the root to a custom selection, that would be great.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400532/jpa-criteria-select-all-instances-with-max-values-in-their-groups. - Check this your approach is wrong. you should not use self join. it will make system slow. select max using subquery and then select record using criteria builder

Comment: Thank you, I'll try out this approach to see if I can get the results I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Course> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Course.class);
Root<Course> root = criteriaQuery.from(Course.class);

criteriaQuery.select(root).where(cb.equal(root.get(Course_.moduleId), 12345));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(cb.desc(r.get(Course_.endDate)));

TypedQuery<Course> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
query.setMaxResult(1);
Course result = query.getSingleResult();
```