# Finding rows with min values in group using Criteria API

Tags: java, sql, criteria-api

I am trying to create a filter query using JPA Criteria API that finds all those entities that have a lowest value in their group.

For example given a JPA entity "Student" mapping a Table similar to:

| id | name | grade | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 | A |
| 2 | Jim | 2 | A |
| 3 | James | 4 | B |
| 4 | Jordan | 3 | B |

I would like to filter this down to the students that have the lowest grade in their class, in this case `John` and `Jordan`.

In SQL this can be accomplished with a self join like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM students s1
inner join(
select class, Min(grade) as max_grade from students group by class 
) s2 on s1.class = s2.class and s1.grade = s2.max_grade;
```

However I am unable to find a way to create a similar self join approach using the JPA Criteria API.

I can not just use JPQL for this as this predicate would have to be added to a large, existing Criteria Predicate.

Comment: I was able to solve this using the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400532/jpa-criteria-select-all-instances-with-max-values-in-their-groups)